# Вылетает приложения PyQT

Tags: python, pyside2

Когда я пытаюсь создать Label в Qt Designer и запустить код приложения не запускается. А если обычный текст все отлично работает.
Ос: Windows10
Python: 3.7.6

Заранее спасибо!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'interface.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(372, 141)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(30, 0, 47, 91))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\ud83d\ude0e", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Сам запуск скрипт просто запускает окно ничего боллее

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль созданный в `Qt Designer` и приложение, которое вы пытаетесь запустить.

Comment: Добавил модуль сгенерированный PyQt в сам вопрос. А скрипт запуска просто чтобы открылось окно

Answer (score 1):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ модуль созданный в `Qt Designer`. Создайте класс и заполните его дизайном. Поменяйте на свои импорты, т.к. я на `PyQt5` и вперед.

```
#from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
#    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
#from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
#    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
#    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
#        if not MainWindow.objectName():
#        MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(372, 141)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(30, 30, 187, 21))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))

#??        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\ud83d\ude0e", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Какой-то Label", None))

    # retranslateUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> С текстом все отлично работает но с смайликами нет

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
#        if not MainWindow.objectName():
#        MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(372, 141)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(50, 50, 287, 71))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))

#??        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\ud83d\ude0e", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "♥ H\u2082SO\u2084 + Be", None)) #

    # retranslateUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 55, QFont.Bold))
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы читали вопрос?

Comment: @Viannedi читал.

Comment: С текстом все отлично работает но с смайликами нет

Comment: @Viannedi попробуйте второй пример и объясните пожалуйста лучше, что у вас не получается.

Comment: Исправил ошибку QT Designer не правильно добавлял смайлики

Comment: @Viannedi вопрос решен или нет? Что значит: `"Исправил ошибку QT Designer не правильно добавлял смайлики"` ?